# ng-class not working with ng-disabled

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I am new to angularJS, I want to change CSS for a button when it is disabled, here is my code :

```
<button ng-hide="spot_id" class="btn ripple" ng-click="Activity()" style=" padding: 4px 12px 4px 12px; color: white;background-color: #00C18B;"  ng-disabled="!name" ng-class="{'select':!name }">Add</button>
```

and in css I have

```
.select{
background-color:red;
}
```

Comment: And your controller?

Comment: css for `:disabled` is quite trivial and has nothing to do with angular. A simple web search would have resolved your problem. Your current css selector may not be specific enough also if another selector is already setting that property

Answer (score 0):

You should add the variable `name` to your scope in a controller where you could set it.
Here is a good tutorial for beginners to learn the basics of angular:
https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_02

Answer (score 0):

It might help to have `ng-class={name}`.  Then in your controller, you'd set `name` to the CSS class name you want for disabled, such as `$scope.name = 'buttonDisabled'`.  Your CSS would have to use `buttonDisabled` as the name as well.